How to repair patio with missing edge on an incline
I bought a house with a patio that is surrounded by a bed of stones which are held in by by a treated wood bar. On the other side of the wood is a 8 inch drop to a vegetable garden. There's a french drain that runs under the rock area between the pavers and the wooden barrier. Unsurprisingly, it's coming apart.

What's the most cost efficient way fix this, assuming I want to get 5-10 years out of it?

Move the stones so the wood can go back together.
Use steel/galvanized strapping/angles to hold/bind the wood together.
If wood is rotted enough to not hold screws(you can push screws in by hand), you need to replace the wood.

Thanks, that seems like a cheap and straightforward way to get this fixed! One thing I noticed though is that the wood curved outward even before it broke. Should I double up the 2x6?

@karmin-pho-er  Screws into the end of wood do not hold as well as in face of the wood, so if there is pressure pushing out(stone/dirt), then extra bindings should be used.

All done. Thanks for the input. I replaced all the pressure treated wood - some of it with wider pieces to avoid gaps at the bottom. I used brackets to hold them together. I also drilled holes through the wood every few feet and hammered rebar through it to keep it from 'bowing' out. I hope that'll hold for a few years.

@karmin-pho-er  Be a good little DIYer and check mark and upvote  crip659's  answer.  That closes the question.

@JACK Done! Can't upvote due to a lack of Karma, but checkmark was added.
